# RSpec - create controller test when the controller is inside a module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

Example

```
module V1
   class HitsController < ApplicationController
   end
end
```

I try access

```
RSpec.describe HitsController, type: :controller do
end
```

but

uninitialized constant HitsController (NameError)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rspec needs to find your class, so you have to tell it where to look at it.

```
RSpec.describe ::V1::HitsController, type: :controller do
end
```